# Integrating noflo and AngularJS using the-graph

Tags: angularjs, html, noflo

I'm working to integrate noflo into AngularJS. For some reason, I've only been able to find an old answer that seemed to direct users wanting to do this to "the-graph", but wasn't super-clear:  github.com/noflo/noflo/issues/286.

I am working to attempt to integrate into AngularJS; if anyone has a working example of doing this, a plukr or fiddle would be appreciated.

Secondly, the "left-click" option that allows editing node properties doesn't appear functional in the-graph example. It seems to work [here](http://app.flowhub.io/#example/7135158), but not [here](http://the-grid.github.io/the-graph/the-graph-editor/index.html). I was wondering how to get the search/properties edit box for each node to function when including inside an existing UI.

So, in sum,

1. How can I get the "left-click" node properties to show up in a custom UI?
2. How can I best integrate noflo into AngularJS? The-graph has a ton of other libraries that appear to need to be added (React, Polymer, HammerJS, KlayJS, KlayJS-NoFlo, etc..)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you hope to achieve. Do you want to:

- Program webapps using NoFlo and AngularJS?
- Make an app (using AngularJS) with a node-editor like the one used in NoFlo UI (the-graph)?
- Or something else?

Comment: Yes, Make an app (using AngularJS) with a node-editor like the one used in NoFlo UI (the-graph)?